# Proving that a function is Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to prove that if $f\in\,C_{c}^{1}(\mathbb{R^3}):=C_{c}^{0}(\mathbb{R^3})\cap C^{1}(\mathbb{R^{3}})$, then the following function is Lebesgue integrable:

$$
y\mapsto \frac{f(y)}{||x-y||}\quad\forall x\in \mathbb{R^3}
$$

That is, the following function:

$$
F(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}{\frac{f(y)}{||x-y||}dy}
$$

is well defined.

So far, I have made the following observations:

- $f$ has a compact support and is continuous over $\mathbb{R^3}$, which means it is Lebesgue integrable.
- $y\mapsto \frac{1}{||y-x||}$ is not integrable, however, since it is being multiplied by a function with compact support, it is equal to zero outside the support of $f$.
- I have been trying to work with the case $x=0$ to see if I get any insight, but I have made no progress so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $y\mapsto \frac{1}{||y-x||}$ is  integrable on any compact subset of $\mathbb R^{n}$ for $n>1$. You can use polar coordinates in $\mathbb R^{n}$ to prove this.

Comment: Of course! I forgot that fact. Thanks!